# Connecting to a ftp server that only allow specific IP address

Tags: networking, ftp, ip, filezilla

I need to connect to a FTP server with restricted IP blocking firewall. The problem is my IP is in dynamic. I only need the FTP to work, I'm using Filezilla. My ISP won't allow me to have a static IP that's the big problem. Is there any way i can make this work? Is proxy an alternative?

Comment: My IP is dynamic too but it never changes. Are you sure that it changes too frequently to simply update your registered IP when it does?

Comment: Most of the time yes. It does change. It's really annoying adding my IP over and over again on the whitelist.

Comment: I see different alternative:
1) Use FTPS on the server
2) Connect go to your FTP through a VPN or a [proxy](http://www.freeproxy.ru/en/free_proxy/faq/ftp_through_proxy.htm)